# Не устанавливается PythonNet под Conda, висит в таком виде очень долго

Tags: anaconda, conda, pythonnet

В чем может быть проблема?
Какие действия можно предпринять?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалась проблема в несовместимости пакетов.
Для версии `pythonnet 2.3.0` требуется максимум `python 3.6.x`
Пришлось удалить `Anaconda3 4.7.3` и установить `Anaconda3-4.3.0` после чего пакет `pythonnet 2.3.0` успешно и моментально установился.